# how to check if one of the input type file is empty or not in python

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery

```
<form method="post">
<input type = "file" name ="file1">
<input type = "file" name ="file1">
<input type = "file" name ="file1">    
</form>
```

I want to check if any of the input fields is empty or not.

Comment: what do you mean empty or not in python? this is just an html form. Are you posting it to some python backend? if so show your code for the python back end that processes this form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vanilla JS (you'll have to fill all inputs):

```js
var inputs = document.getElementById("form").getElementsByTagName("input");
function check(){
  for(let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
    if(inputs[i].value == ''){
      console.log("input something!");
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form method="post" id="form" onsubmit="return check()">
<input type = "file" name ="file1">
<input type = "file" name ="file1">
<input type = "file" name ="file1">  
<button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

jQuery:

```js
var inputs = $('input');
function check(){
  for(let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
    if($(inputs[i]).val() == ''){
      console.log("input something");
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" id="form" onsubmit="return check()">
<input type = "file" name ="file1">
<input type = "file" name ="file1">
<input type = "file" name ="file1">  
<button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the **blur** function for this purpose.

```js
        $('input[type="file"]').blur(function(){
            if(!$(this).val()){
                //Put the code if not a file
            } else{
                //put the code here if file is present
            }
        });
```

```html
<form method="post">
<input type = "file" name ="file1">
<input type = "file" name ="file1">
<input type = "file" name ="file1">    
</form>
```

Comment: There is no blur event if user never touched it

Comment: @charlietfl than what is this referring to? https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-check-if-an-input-field-is-empty-using-jquery.php#:~:text=Answer%3A%20Use%20the%20jQuery%20val,inputs%20are%20empty%20in%20jQuery.

Comment: For one thing that is referring to text input not file input and also assuming that user focused the input. Think about what if user hits submit without doing anything else?